# Vue chunk-vendors bloated by runtime

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

[image: Chunk too large]

I've created a pretty simple vue app, no big plugins or anything, all views are chunked into their own files, this one is only node_modules.

Looking around people are saying vue+vuex+vue-router should be less than 100Kb, my runtime alone is 222kb. Every time I build my application I get a warning that my chunk vendor file is too large but its being pushed over the threshold by vue itself. The biggest modules are:

Full chunk-vendors file size: 494Kb

vue.runtime.esm.js - 222kb

Elliptic - 109kb

bn.js - 85kb

vue-router - 73kb

Why aren't any of these being minified?

Comment: How you importing vuex, router to index file where you are creating vue instance ?

Comment: @MandeepGill
const router = () => import('./router')
const store = () => import('./store/store')

inside main.js